# Symfony __construct

Tags: php, symfony4

Мне нужно реализовать статистику посещения на сайте, хотел в конструкторе всю логику прописать, но доктрину не получается вызвать из конструктора, пишет

```
Call to a member function has() on null

$visitRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('App:VisitStatistics');
```

Можно ли вызвать констракт или как иначе?
Ошибка

```
protected function getDoctrine(): ManagerRegistry    
{        
    if (!$this->container->has('doctrine')) {            
        throw new \LogicException('The DoctrineBundle is not registered in your application. Try running "composer require symfony/orm-pack".');       
    }        

    return $this->container->get('doctrine');    
}
```

Вызвать пытаюсь в конструкторе базового контроллера, который наследуется от Controller

Comment: Из вопроса не ясно. В конструкторе чего хотели прописать логику. И что вызывает указанную ошибку? has() какого класса вызываете и где?

Comment: Это доктрина внутри себя вызывает где-то. В базовом контроллере, обновил тему

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы используете четверку, то пора уже забыть про контейнер, а инжектить все что требуется. `EntityManager` насколько я помню имеет `EntityManagerInterface`, поэтому его надо заинжектить в конструктор:

```
public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em) 
{
    $this->repository = $em->getRepository('repoName');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вызвать getDoctrine в конструкторе не выйдет, поскольку метод setContainer контроллера выполняется после конструктора и соответственно container равен null в момент создания объекта и вызов `$this->container->has('doctrine')` вызывает указанную вами ошибку

Comment: Почему так происходит я понял. А как решить?

Comment: не "писать всю логику в конструкторе". Вы бы поделились, как хотите реализовать статистику и почему именно в конструкторе?

Comment: Чтобы на какую страницу бы не зашел юзер, к нему применялась эта логика. Реализовать хочу так: Беру айпи, по нему определяю город, записываю юзера и город в бд с сегодняшней датой, если это уже есть, то прибавляю количество кликов

Comment: По моему это лучше делать в событиях. например https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-terminate после отдачи контента. заодно и меньше тормозов будет